# Double hopping credentials from VSTS through Azure PowerShell script to PowerShell script on target VM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I need to automate execution of scripts on target VMs as a domain administrator. The problem is, VMs don't have public. I also should not rewrite the script as it has been written by a team member and I'd rather provide my team with a solution that works for them and is automatable, instead of rewriting their scripts every time.
The current  process looks like thi

1. VSTS initiates a build process with Azure PowerShell script command1.ps1
2. Command1.ps1 installs Azure Custom Script Extension on the target VM
3. Custom script extension downloads and executes command2.ps1 that runs command3.ps1 as a domain administrator

The problem I'm having is I'm unable to pass credentials from VSTS to command2.ps1
Please, recommend me how I should do that properly.
The options I found:

1. Not sure if it is possible with VSTS https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/
2. Add IP public address to the target VM, configure WinRM, execute command2.ps1, delete public IP address

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this.
command1.ps1:

```
    param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$resourceGroupName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$targetVMname,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$vmLocation,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$FileUri,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$nameOfTheScriptToRun,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$customScriptExtensionName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$domainAdminName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$domainAdminPassword

)

$domainAdminPasswordSecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $domainAdminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$DomainCredentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $domainAdminName, $domainAdminPasswordSecureString

Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -Argument "-DomainCredentials $DomainCredentials" `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -VMName $targetVMname `
    -Location $vmLocation `
    -FileUri $FileUri `
    -Run $nameOfTheScriptToRun `
    -Name $customScriptExtensionName

Remove-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -Force `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -VMName $targetVMname `
    -Name $customScriptExtensionName
```

command2.ps1:

```
    param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$DomainCredentials
)

$url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/x/command2.ps1"
$output = "C:\command2.ps1"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList $output -Credential $DomainCredentials
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually have the double hop problem, because you are not executing the command on the node, you are launching the extension, which downloads the script and executes it.

So what you need to do is this:

```
Set-AzureRMVMCustomScriptExtension ... -Argument "-domainAdminName admin -domainAdminPassword passw0rD" -VM $Vm
$vm | Update-AzureVM
```

and in your script (which is invoked INSIDE the machine, so command2.ps1) do:

```
$domainAdminPasswordSecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $domainAdminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$DomainCredentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $domainAdminName, $domainAdminPasswordSecureString
```

and paste the appropriate params into the second script (so it accepts those)

Also, you don't need the intermediate script, you can just download `"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/x/command2.ps1"` and execute it with arguments

Comment: Are you proposing to pass plain text password from VSTS through Azure Custom Extension? I don't think that's a good idea. The password will visible as plain text inside C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.9\RuntimeSettings\0.settings

Comment: you are removing the extension afterwards, so doesn't really matter. that place will be cleaned up. Or you can use protected settings and the command to execute will be encoded. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript

Comment: Any way to pass protected settings with PowerShell? If not, what would you do? Would you feel safe passing password as simple string?

Comment: `-SecureExecution`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmcustomscriptextension?view=azurermps-4.4.0

Comment: So, this should do the trick?
`Set-AzureRMVMCustomScriptExtension ... -Argument "-domainAdminName admin" -SecureExecution "-domainAdminPassword passw0rD" -VM $Vm`
?

Comment: Although, thanks to this answer double hop issues is avoided, a new issue of Azure Custom Script Extension appeared. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433123/azure-custom-script-extension-execute-script-as-another-user

Comment: in this case you probably want to accept this answer ;)