# Azure Powershell Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied

Tags: powershell, azure

I created the below code & its getting failed because of the access denied error for start process while executing powershell.exe.

```
$username = "domain\username"

$password = "Welcome1234$"

$PSArgs = "D:\test.ps1"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username,

$securePassword

Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential $credential $PSArgs
```

Error:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied  
Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied.
At C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\PRISMA-AMR-JOB1-87-ScriptBuildTask-8569094554411403512.ps1:38 char:18
+     Start-Process <<<<  C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -arg "/C" -Credential $credential + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

> Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error:
>   Access is denied. At
>   C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\PRISMA-AMR-JOB1-87-ScriptBuildTask-8569094554411403512.ps1:38
>   char:18

According to this error code, it seems you have not add your user "domain\username" to local computer policy -> User Rights Assignment.

[image]

More information about **User Rights Assignment**, please refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221963%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Also, here a similar case, please refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912320/powershell-start-process-this-command-cannot-be-executed-due-to-the-error-acc).

**Note**:

To open the Local Group Policy, at a command prompt or in Search, type `gpedit.msc`, and then click OK or press `ENTER`.

Comment: The domain user is already added the local policy"Impersonate a client after authentication".

Comment: @hans Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @hans can we run this script with your domain user?